# Using :not to exclude selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm ok with CSS, but its not really my bag. I've been trying to work out the most efficient way of setting my base selectors.

For example:

```
h3:not([class])
{
    /* make it look good */
}
```

The example above lets me set a base h3, then if I want to exclude the base styling, I just add a class.

However, the most challenging is the anchor which appears in lots of places throughout the site - main menu, footer links, quick links, related links, pseudo buttons - you get the picture. There are lots of different styles I might wan't to use to style an anchor, so I need to remove the default styling each time.

I can of course take the same approach as above, but the main difference with the anchor element is that it tends to be used in bunches inside UL/LI elements, so it doesn't cover this scenario.

Is there any way I can exclude any links with a parent LI or is it just a case of cascading something like this?

```
a:not([class])
{
    /* make it look good */
}
li > a:not([class])
{
    /* remove the goodness */
}
```

Comment: It is just like you need to limit it within the parent selector. I don't understand your question, but does this answer you? I guess @BoltClock can answer you better!

Comment: You might be better off using classes to apply styling, rather than remove it - that's the normal way of doing things. Divide into base styling for very general stuff (normalize, fonts etc). But largely wrap any styling in classes. If a particular component wants to modify that styling it can do `.footer-component .large-heading` etc. Generally avoid styling global elements like `a` and `h1`, if you really want to then limit the scope e.g. `.main h1`

Comment: Do you basically want `li > a:not([class])` to have the same styles as `a[class]`?

Comment: No - see the comment

Comment: Let me rephrase - do you want to apply your styles to `a:not([class])` except those with a `li` parent?

Answer (score 0):

I appeciate the answers given.

In the end this is what works for me - it could work for others.

For simple cases

```
h1:not([class])
{
    /* Excludes H1's with a class */
}
```

For complex cases inside lists

```
*:not(li) > a:not([class]),
ul.base > li > a
{
    /* Excludes any A with a class or that is a child in a list
       Includes an A inside a list if the UL is appended with the class "base" */
}
```